# SpriteKit BoundingBox detection texture change

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, detection, bounding-box

Edit: Hi at all! (forgot to say hello...)

I got a pretty annoying problem.

I've created a small program which works quite good so far. However, I'm trying to change an SKSpriteNode texture whenever it's hovering over another SKSpriteNode.
To test the implementation I added an NSLog() to print the hovered nodes origin.
THAT works. But the texture change only works when hovering over the last itereated node.
Complicated. Here is some code:

```
-(void)checkAimingHover{

for (SKSpriteNode *childSprite in [parentNode children]) {
        CGRect boundingBox =
        CGRectMake(childSprite.position.x-childSprite.size.width/2,
                   childSprite.position.y-childSprite.size.height/2,
                   childSprite.frame.size.width,
                   childSprite.frame.size.height);
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(boundingBox, aiming.position)) {
            // THIS works like a charm
            NSLog(@"%f/%f",boundingBox.origin.x, boundingBox.origin.y); 
            // THIS only works on the last created boundingBox
            [aiming setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"aim_hover"]]; 
        } else [aiming setTexture:aimDefault];


    }
}
```

aming: SKSpriteNode *aiming;

And the small update():

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

    if (lastUpdateTime) {
        deltaTime = currentTime - lastUpdateTime;
    } else {
        deltaTime = 0;
    }
    lastUpdateTime = currentTime;

    [self checkAimingHover];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting your texture on each loop. Try this instead:

```
   BOOL hitTestDidHit = NO;
   for (SKSpriteNode *childSprite in [parentNode children]) {
    CGRect boundingBox =
    CGRectMake(childSprite.position.x-childSprite.size.width/2,
               childSprite.position.y-childSprite.size.height/2,
               childSprite.frame.size.width,
               childSprite.frame.size.height);
     if (CGRectContainsPoint(boundingBox, aiming.position)) {
        // THIS works like a charm
        NSLog(@"%f/%f",boundingBox.origin.x, boundingBox.origin.y); 
        // THIS only works on the last created boundingBox
        hitTestDidHit = YES;
     }
    }


    if(hitTestDidHit) {
        [aiming setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"aim_hover"]]; 
    } else {
        [aiming setTexture:aimDefault];
    }
```

Also I should tell you about the super cool .calculateAccumulatedFrame property which pretty much does what your bounding box does but with children as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this doesn't work either :/

Comment: Try to put a NSLog after both the lines where you set the textures (log out different things though like "A" and "B"), and see if it looks like they're being triggered at the right time.

Comment: Works like a charm for the output.
Got my prints on every boundingBox...
http://cxg.de/_0741cc.htm

Comment: I'm entirely sorry. Your way was totally right. I was just stupid enough to put
    BOOL hitTestDidHit = NO;
INTO the for loop...
Once I put it outside, the hovering works flawlessly! Thank you!!

And thanks for the hint to .calculateAccumulatedFrame too! :D

Comment: However, I don't really get why the output worked but the hover only on the recent nodes...

Comment: It would have always worked on the very last node. The latest node wouldn't reset the aiming texture.

For instance. Imagine you have two objects in your children.

1. Object IS in the aiming zone. So it sets the texture to aiming.
2. Second object is NOT in the aiming zone, so it sets it back.
The net result is that the aiming isn't set.

Imagine the other way around.
1. First object is NOT in the aiming zone, so it sets the aiming sprite to normal.
2. Second object IS in the aiming zone, so it sets the aiming sprite to aiming.
Net result is that the aiming sprite looks right. :)